# Django - How does order_by work?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sql-order-by

I'd like to know how Django's `order_by` works if the given `order_by` field's values are same for a set of records. Consider I have a `score` field in DB and I'm filtering the queryset using `order_by('score')`. How will records having the same values for score arrange themselves?

Every time, they're ordered randomly within the subset of records having equal score and this breaks the pagination at client side. Is there a way to override this and return the records in a consistent order?

I'm Using Django 1.4 and PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`order_by` can have multiple params, I think `order_by('score', '-create_time')` will always return the same queryset.

Answer (score 17):

As the other answers correctly explain, `order_by()` accepts multiple arguments. I'd suggest using something like:

```py
qs.order_by('score','pk') #where qs is your queryset
```

I recommend using `'pk'` (or `'-pk'`) as the last argument in these cases, since every model has a `pk` field and its value is never the same for 2 records.

Comment: -1 this answer was already given 2 times, no need for a third time, you could have edited their posts to clean up the coding parts

Comment: Neither of the answers is completely accurate for the OP's needs. `order_by('id', 'score')` will sort by 'id' first, then by 'score', which is not what he needs. `order_by('score', '-create_time')` is not accurate since it uses an unknown column. Neither of the answers mentioned using `pk` which is universal.

Comment: point taken, but then again thats a minor comment on their posts and doesn't require a largely duplicate anwser

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, I think you need consistently ordered result set every time, You can use something like `order_by('score','id')` that will first order by the score first and then by the auto-increment `id` within the `score` having same values, hence your output being consistent. The documentation is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by). You need to be explicit in the order_by if you want to fetch correct result set every time, using 'id' is one of the ways.